# Bootstrap-vue modal with fullscreen-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**I use:**

[bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/)

[fullscreen-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fullscreen)

And I have a simple project [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-6stjl?fontsize=14).

There are many different modals in project. As not to create unnecessary methods (open, close, ... ) due to amount of popups with diffetent logic I use `this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm` with `then`.

**Template:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fullscreen ref="fullscreen" @change="fullscreenChange" class="h-100">
      <router-view/>
    </fullscreen>

    <div class="fullscreen-toggle">
      <a href="#" @click="toggleFullscreen" class="btn btn-warning">
        <span v-if="!fullscreen" class="fullscreen-btn">+</span>
        <span v-if="fullscreen" class="fullscreen-btn">-</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data () {
    return {
      fullscreen: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.$refs['fullscreen'].toggle()
    },
    fullscreenChange (fullscreen) {
      this.fullscreen = fullscreen
    },
    toggleFullscreen () {
      this.$store.commit('toggleFullscreen');
    },
  },
  created () {
    //console.log('App created')
    this.$store.watch(
      (state) => {
        return this.$store.state.fullscreen // could also put a Getter here
      },
      (newValue, oldValue)=>{
        this.$refs['fullscreen'].toggle()
        //something changed do something
        console.log(oldValue)
        console.log(newValue)
      },
      //Optional Deep if you need it
      {
        deep:true
      }
    )
  }
};
</script>
```

And I want show **"+"** if `fullscreen: false`, **"-"** if `fullscreen: true` , but nothing work.

**Quastion:** How I can use fullscreen-vue with multiple bootstrap-vue modals?

Comment: You are referencing the `fullscreen` inside the component and not the `fullscreen` from Vuex. Change the reference to `$store.state.fullscreen`.